# Blacklisting fields from elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Hi friends am new on elasticsearch. I want to know if I can exclude certain fields from search from elastic search. To eloborate I want to ignore it from my search. It should not search that field when we specify but should be searchable on all the fields other then thats blacklisted.

In the below data i want to search for **Product ABC** in all other fields other then Service_Sold.Product_Name. I cam across excludes and whitelisting methods which is not feasible as we have lots of fields in index and would increase the complexity of the query.

Would appreciate any suggestions and help.

Note 7.10 version elastic-seach
running queries on KIBANA

Here is the sample search query data.

```
{
        "_index" : "_dev",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "data-2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "datas",
          "id_number" : 736762732784934,
          "company_group_name" : "Customer ABC name 2",
          "company_group_id" : 2,
          "document_title" : "Product ABC title_736762732784934",
          "effective_date" : "2011-01-26",
          "Service_Sold" : [
            {
              "Type" : "Type XYZ",
              "Product_Name" : "Product ABC"
            }
          ]
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
GET {YOUR_INDEX_NAME}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "Product ABC"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "Service_Sold.Product_Name": "Product ABC"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In your mapping the fields `Service_Sold` must be `nested`
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Thanks fr the quick reply. Pape BADIANE but there is a drawback here not able to use multiple phrases. Assuming we have another field called Service_Sold.Product_desciption = "Product ABC"

Comment: can you show an example please ?

Comment: Can u pls find the below attached comment @Pape BADIANE

Comment: The requirement is even if a Product_Name has keyword "Product " we should search only in Product_Description. And return the result  with only with Service_Sold. Product_Description if not then return null

Comment: ok i see your need, but i dont thing it is possible to exclude Service_Sold.Product_Description

Comment: OK Thanks for confimation. I will see if i can change the meta info to attain this solution

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        "_index" : "_dev",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "data-2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "datas",
          "id_number" : 736762732784934,
          "company_group_name" : "Customer ABC name 2",
          "company_group_id" : 2,
          "document_title" : "Product ABC title_736762732784934",
          "effective_date" : "2011-01-26",
          "Service_Sold" : [
            {
              "Type" : "Type XYZ",
              "Product_Name" : "Product ABC",
              "Product_Description" : "Product ABC"
            }
          ]
        }
 }
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.